# Optimizing query to grab results from two tables

Tags: postgresql

Lets say I have a db table called Document that contains rows for all the documents I own. I have another db table called Shared that has records for all documents (owned by other people) that I can read/write to.

```
Document
id
type
user_id
permissions

Shared
id
document_id
used_id
permissions
```

I was trying to write a query that would get me back all documents that I (given a user_id) own and have access to. My attempt is something like this:

```
Select id, type, user_id, permissions from Document where user_id = 123
union all
Select id, type, user_id, permissions from Document where id in
                                   (select document_id from shared where user_id = 123)
```

The above seems a little bit verbose so I was wondering if there was a more succinct/efficient way to write the above (if it works at all)

Answer (score 2):

Try using left join + where clause

```
Select d.id, d.type, d.user_id, d.permissions from Document d
left join shared s on s.document_id = d.id
                    and s.user_id = d.user_id
where d.user_id = 123
and s.document_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I'm a little inexperienced at sql, but I thought a join on the document_id = d.id required the same document to be present in both tables? There could be cases where I want documents that are just for me in the documents table and documents that dont exist for me in the documents table but I do have access to in the shared table because my user_id is on a row in that table

Comment: that is where the left join + where clause comes in. basically, it will include all entries in `Document` table that is present in `shared` table, if it does not find an entry within `shared` table, it will return the data set as null, and that is where the `where` clause comes in

Comment: i've also updated the answer to use the proper column names to prevent ambiguous column name errors

Comment: I tried a simple version and couldnt quite get it to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a5ed/7

Comment: Hi, I looked at  your fiddle and I saw that your document_id = 4, I think it should be 1

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a5ed/9

Comment: You were right, but I would think http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a5ed/10 works but it doesnt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124686/discussion-between-john-baum-and-james-joyce-alano).